# Well-formed formula, Inductive Definition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

So I have to inductively define:

1. The number of propositional variables of a "Well-formed formula"
2. The set of propositional variables of a "Well-formed formula"
3. The set of parenthesis in a "Well-formed formula"
4. The number of parenthesis in a "Well-formed formula"

and I don't know where to start from, some little help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is your trouble that you don't know what an inductive definition is, or that you don't know what a well-formed formula is, or that you don't know what propositional variables are, or something else?

Comment: Yeah I do know what an inductive definition and propositional variables are, I just simply do not know how to apply them to these problems.

Comment: You have to start writing down the *inductive definition* of well-formed formula. Then, each properties of well-formed formualae must be defined/described following the steps of the inductive definition. Example: step 1 of the inductive def is : evry prop variable is a wff; thus step 1 of the "calculation" of the number of prop var in a wff is : $1$.

Comment: For the first, I assume we want the number of *instances* of propositional variables. So we are defining a function $f$ from wff to the natural numbers. If $X$ is a propositional variable, then $f(X)=1$. If $\phi$ is $\lnot\psi$ then $f(\phi)=f(\psi)$. If $\phi$ is $(\alpha\land \beta)$ then $f(\phi)=f(\alpha)+f(\beta)$. The same sort of thing for the other binary connectives.

Answer (score 1):

This of course depends on what your definition of a "well-formed formula" is. Let's say a well-formed formula is any formula generated by the following grammar.

$$\varphi ::= p \; | \; \neg(\varphi) \; | \;(\varphi_1 \wedge \varphi_2) \; | \; (\varphi_1 \rightarrow \varphi_2), $$

where $p$ is a propositional variable. Then we can define a function $f$ that, given a well-formed formula, returns the number of propositional variables in the formula inductively by

- $f(p) = 1$
- $f(\neg(\varphi)) = f(\varphi)$
- $f(\varphi_1 \wedge \varphi_2) = f(\varphi_1) + f(\varphi_2)$
- $f(\varphi_1 \rightarrow \varphi_2) = f(\varphi_1) + f(\varphi_2)$

This is also called *pattern matching*, because we define the function structurally by each identifiable pattern in the grammar. With this example, I hope you will be able to solve the last three problems on your own.